# Disable button inside bootgrid dynamic

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-bootgrid

Now i have a bootgrid table to download files using bootgrid.I have written a formatter for that and it works well.

```
"commands": function(column, row) {
    return '<a href="'+row["slink"]+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.id + '">Download</buttn></a> ';
}
```

Where slink gives the download location of file for corresponding row with row id id..

Now the problem is that some rows dont have any files and row[slink] will return blank.When user clicks a blank row the page just refresh.

Now what i want to do is to disable the download button when the slink value is blank.How can i achieve this? It would be greatif i could change the button text  from download to something like Not available it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix your problem, replaces your formatter with this:

```
"commands": function(column, row) {
    if (row["slink"] == null || row["slink"] == '')
        return "";
    return '<a href="'+row["slink"]+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " data-row-id="' + row.id + '">Download</buttn></a> ';
}
```

We just check if the row has an empty or null `slink`. If it has, we return an empty string instead of an `<a></a>` tag.